# Git Clone and Getting Patch File

Tags: git

I downloaded Android sources with git clone.I made some modifications and i want to create a patch file using below command,

```
diff -Nur sourcefolder changedfolder > changes.patch
```

but it gives such errors,

```
diff: TI-Android-ICS-4.0.3-DevKit-EVM-SK-3.0.1/abi/cpp/.git/svn: No such file or directory
diff: rowboat/abi/cpp/.git/svn: No such file or directory
diff: TI-Android-ICS-4.0.3-DevKit-EVM-SK-3.0.1/bionic/.git/svn: No such file or directory
diff: rowboat/bionic/.git/svn: No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to get a clean patch file?

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://luhman.org/blog/2009/09/22/git-patch-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `diff` command also inspects the `.git` folders.
You should try [`git diff`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) to create your patch.

Something like 
`git diff --patch <originalcommit>..<yourcommit> > patch.file`
should work.
But your changes have to be (locally) committed first.